# Libraries Not Loaded After Cache Clear / Reload

Tags: theming

I'm experiencing a problem with drupal 8

whenever I clear the cache, my custom theme's libraries(ex: the css and js) will not be loaded

and I must reinstall the whole drupal to make it works again

is there anything I can do to trace the source of the problem ?
Nothing strange is being logged in nginx and php's error log

Answer (score 2):

Solved

this issue occurred because I've another custom module with the same name as the theme.